# Iterate over Vec<"CustomStruct"> => unsatisfied trait bounds

Tags: rust

I'm participating in this year's Advent of Code and wanted to take the opportunity to learn Rust. (So, if you're also participating, the following section might spoil something).

I want to iterate over the Vec vector and decrement the internal_counter value for each Item in this Vector. I tried the following:
`let test: Vec<Lanternfish> = fish_list.map(|fish| fish.decrement_couner()).collect();`

The compiler gives me the following error: `method cannot be called on Vec<Lanternfish> due to unsatisfied trait bounds`
I understand that the iterator function is not available for this, however I don't understand exactly how to fix the problem.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Lanternfish {
    internal_counter: u8,
}

impl Lanternfish {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Lanternfish {
            internal_counter: 8,    
        }
    }

    fn decrement_counter(&mut self) {
        self.internal_counter -= 1
    }
}

fn part_one(content: &str) {
    let content: Vec<char> = content.chars().filter(|char| char.is_digit(10)).collect();   
    let mut fish_list: Vec<Lanternfish> = init_list(content);

    let test: Vec<Lanternfish> = fish_list.map(|fish| fish.decrement_counter()).collect();
}

fn init_list(initial_values: Vec<char>) -> Vec<Lanternfish> {
    let mut all_lanternfish: Vec<_> = Vec::new();
    for value in initial_values {
        all_lanternfish.push(Lanternfish{internal_counter: value as u8});
    }
    all_lanternfish
}
```

Comment: You don't call  `map` on a `Vec` but on an `Iterable`. You get the iterable with `iter()`. So mapping on a vec starts usually with `fish_list.iter().map(...`

Comment: `map()` doesn't really exist for a vector, the compiler is trying to be helpful, but ends up being confusing. You need to iterate over the vector, e.g. with `fish_list.into_iter()`, on which you can call `map()` and other iterator methods. And then you need to actually call `decrement_counter()` rather than just mention it. For example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d80813582c09208720bf8e2ab2947b82

Comment: Also, `decrement_counter()` mutates the object, so you really want to iterate over the vector and call it on each element, not map and collect into a new vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to iterate over a `Vec` and call a mutating function on each element is:

```
for fish in &mut fish_list {
  fish.decrement_counter();
}
```

What this line is doing:

```
fish_list.map(|fish| fish.decrement_couner).collect();
```

is

- Try to call `map` on the `Vec` (it doesn't have that. `Iterator` has it, but you'd need to call `iter()`, `iter_mut()` or `into_iter()` on the `Vec` for that).
- Assuming you get the right `map`, it then calls the lambda `|fish| fish.decrement_couner` on each element; typo aside, this is not a function call, but a field access, and `Lanternfish` doesn't have a field called `decrement_couner`. A call would need parentheses.
- Assuming you fix the function call, you then collect all the results of the calls (a bunch of `()` "unit" values, since `decrement_counter` doesn't return anything) into a new `Vec`, which is of type `Vec<()>`.
- And finally, you try to bind that to a variable of `Vec<Lanternfish>`, which will fail.

Meanwhile, the function calls will have modified the original `Vec`, if you used `iter_mut()`. Otherwise, the function calls will not compile.

Comment: Thank you, that made it much clearer to me. I have a follow up question. I want to push a new fish to the fish_list Vector, if the internal_counter of a fish is 0. So something like this: 
`for fish in &mut fish_list { 
  fish.decrement_counter(); 
  fish_list.push(Lanternfish::new()); 
} `
 That does not work, because i double-borrow the list. Is there a "easy" solution to this or do I have to create 2 fish_lists, one to iterate over and the other to append new fish?

Comment: I'd keep a counter of how many 0-fish I found during iteration, then after the loop is done push that many fish to the end.